# How to truncate links to certain length using any of the javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checked the web thoroughly but haven't found anything that tell how to truncate links to certain length

Comment: Truncate the `href` link source, or truncate the text inside the `<a></a>` tags?

Comment: the text between the <a></a> tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
jQuery("a").each(function(i, value) {
   var $link = jQuery(value);
   var text = $link.text();

   if(text.length > 25) {
      $link.text(text.substring(0, 21) + "...");
   }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for earlier, I tried it again and it worked great. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to truncate the text inside the links:

```
$('a').text(function(index, oldText) {
    if (oldText.length > 10) {
        return oldText.substring(0, 10) + '...';
    }
    return oldText;
});
```

and here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/vsujC/

Comment: @user715679, are you sure, as the following example http://jsfiddle.net/vsujC/ seems to work?

Comment: @user715679 The above code is correct, however you may be noticing an issue with jQuery 1.5.1 and jsFiddle. Try loading jsFiddle in another browser or with jQuery 1.5 and you should see the correct results. For reference, there seems to be an issue with jQuery 1.5.1/jsFiddle when loaded in Chrome.

Comment: Yes there was an issue, and it worked fine , thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to write the same solution as others have provided:

```
$('a').text(function(index, oldText) {
    return oldText.length > 10 ? oldText.substring(0, 10) + '...' : oldText;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vsujC/1/

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified the version of Vivin's code to only truncate "http://" links:

```
// Truncate long http:// links
// ===============================
$("a").each(function(i, value) {
  var $link = $(value);
  var text = $link.text();

  if(text.length > 45 && text.toLowerCase().indexOf("http://") >= 0) {
    $link.text(text.substring(0, 41) + "...");
  }
});
```

So it turns links like that

> http://website.com/admin/articles/leucemie-lymphoblastique-aigue-pediatrique-et-sequelles-neuropsychologiques-un-apercu-des-connaissances-actuelles

into

> [http://website.com/admin/articles/leucemi...](http://website.com/admin/articles/leucemie-lymphoblastique-aigue-pediatrique-et-sequelles-neuropsychologiques-un-apercu-des-connaissances-actuelles)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by a simple CSS trick. Try this:

```
.truncateText { max-width: 100px; overflow: hidden; 
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis; -o-text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; }
```

Now use this css-class and apply the same to the HTML elements you want to truncate text.

`For your scenario`, you can rename the class as

```
a { max-width: 100px; ...
```

Hope this will help you.